# Batch delayed expansion not working as expected

Tags: batch-file

I have written below sample batch script, variable COUNT is getting updated but somehow MY_ROOT is not getting updated, am I missing something here ?

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set MY_ROOT= C:\
set COUNT=0

if 1 == 1 (  
  set MY_ROOT = D:\ 
  echo MY_ROOT = !MY_ROOT!

  set /A COUNT=10 
  echo Count = !COUNT!
)
:end

**o/p:**
MY_ROOT =  C:\
Count = 10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386697/why-is-no-string-output-with-echo-var-after-using-set-var-text-on-comman)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaces are significant on **both** sides of a string `set` statement. You are assigning a variable called "MY_ROOT<kbd>Space</kbd>"

Answer (score 2):

One of the most confusing 'features' in batch files is that the spaces become part of the variable name.Remove the spaces around equal sign when you are using `SET`. You can use also quotes like in the code bellow for more safe value assignment.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "MY_ROOT=C:\"
set COUNT=0

if 1 == 1 (  
  set "MY_ROOT=D:\"
  echo MY_ROOT = !MY_ROOT!

  set /A COUNT=10 
  echo Count = !COUNT!
)
:end
```